# How to view child nodes of a parent from panda dataframe?

Tags: mongodb, pandas

I was trying to extract data from mongodb. So, I was using panda as a dataframe. I was using twitter dataset. The dataset was in json and when I import it in the database it looks like this:

```
    user:Object
        id:1292598776
        id_str:1292598776
        name:ahmd
        screen_name:sameh7753
        location:
        url:null
        description:null
        protected:false
        followers_count:5
        friends_count:76
        listed_count:0
        created_at:Sat Mar 23 21:59:37 +0000 2013
        favourites_count:1
        utc_offset:null
        time_zone:null
        geo_enabled:true
        lang:ar
        contributors_enabled:false
        is_translator:false
        profile_background_color:C0DEED
        profile_use_background_image:true
        default_profile:true
        default_profile_image:false
        follow_request_sent:null
```

So, here 'user' is the parent and under it there are many children.There are other fields too in the dataset.
So, I was trying to execute a query which will find any tweet, tweeted on 2013 and the location of the tweet is `"US"`. And then I was storing those cursors in the panda data frame. So when I was printing the data frame I was expecting to see those `screen_name` but it was not getting printed and also I couldn't access those data.

Here is the code I was using:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

def _connect_mongo(host, port, db):
    conn = MongoClient(host, port)
    return conn[db]


def read_mongo(db, collection, host, port):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, db=db)

    cursor = db[collection].find({'created_at':{'$regex': '2013'}},
    {'place.country':'US'}, no_cursor_timeout=True).toArray()

    print cursor

    # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))


    return df

db = 'twittersmall' #'twitter'
collection='twitterdata' #'twitterCol' #
#query={'lang':'{$exists: true}'}
host='localhost'
port=27017

var = read_mongo(db, collection, host, port)

print var
```

It only prints under the `user` column in panda data frame this:

```
False  {u'follow_request_sent':
u'profile_use_b...
```

And rest of the attributes don't get print and I can't even access them by writing `var['user.screen_name']` stated in the python code.
How can I access the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to include `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`.
Now your `read_mongo` function should be like this-

```
def read_mongo(db, collection, host, port):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, db=db)

    cursor = db[collection].find({'created_at':{'$regex': '2013'}},
     no_cursor_timeout=True)

    cursor = list(cursor)    
    df = json_normalize(cursor)

    return df
```

Here `json_normalaize` flattens those fields which have children and make them columns of the panda dataframe.